# Loading some json objects

Tags: typescript, angular

I load some json:

```
[{
        "id": "0a4bf3b5bb5f47ece9284052389ae02f6c9dba989ca34086a30e049ee3d8eb47",
        "name": "Celery",
        "status": "Offline",
        "servicecontrolled": true
},
{
        "id": "ec9471ec001c10b9fa286e1f52e39c5dc9485a7c2cfbf55145c26242bb98ec4d",
         "name": "Nginx",
         "status": "Online",
         "servicecontrolled": false
}]
```

and show `servicecontrolled` in html:

```
 <td>
    <span>{{ service_rec.servicecontrolled }}</span>
 </td>
```

How to show only `"servicecontrolled": true` in html code?

Comment: can you please post the complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Now that the question is more precise, what you could do is:

```
<td>
    <span *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled">"servicecontrolled": {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json }}</span>
</td>
```

**Old answer** (thought you wanted to display “true” or “false”):
What about:

```
<td>
    <span>"servicecontrolled": {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json }}</span>
</td>
```

Seems like a trick, but very straightforward…

Or you could write a boolean pipe that would format boolean to string (see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).

Something like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'booleantostring'})
export class BooleanToStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: boolean): string {
    return (!!value) ? 'true' : 'false';
  }
}
```

then, in your html (with the pipe loaded in the `pipes` key of the `@component` decorator):

```
<td>
    <span>"servicecontrolled": {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | booleantostring }}</span>
</td>
```

Comment: all also remains, true and false are show, but i would to see only true values

Comment: aaaaaaah… ok… I’ve updated my answer (you should be more precise in your question)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is syntactically incorrect. 
It should look like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0a4bf3b5bb5f47ece9284052389ae02f6c9dba989ca34086a30e049ee3d8eb47",
        "name": "Celery",
        "status": "Offline",
        "servicecontrolled": true
    },
    {
        "id": "ec9471ec001c10b9fa286e1f52e39c5dc9485a7c2cfbf55145c26242bb98ec4d",
         "name": "Nginx",
         "status": "Online",
         "servicecontrolled": false
    }
]
```

Then you can show it with

```
<div *ngFor='let value of values' *ngIf='value.servicecontrolled'>
    {{ value.name }}
</div>
```

Comment: yes, i know, because I put only part of my code, but not full

Comment: @EduardArevshatyan you might want to fix your question then

Comment: I think i know, what you are looking. Take a look to my edit.